# Call methods on jquery combobox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox

Still trying to figure out jQuery. I'm using the Autocomplete widget with the combobox. I have a requirement to have the drop-down list show on page load and when another combobox gets selected. So, I'm trying to add the Autocomplete search method on the combobox code and I don't know how. What I've tried isn't working. Here is the last thing I've tried. You'll see I've added the search function at the bottom. thanks for the help.

I'm getting this error right now:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'search'

Here is my calling code:

```
$("select").combobox();
$("select").combobox("search","");
```

Here is my widget code:

```
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "ui.combobox", {
  _create: function() {
    var self = this;
    var select = this.element.hide(),
      selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
      value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
    var input = $( "<input />" )
      .insertAfter(select)
      .val( value )
      .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
          response( select.children("option" ).map(function() {
            var text = $( this ).text();
            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
              return {
                label: text.replace(
                  new RegExp(
                    "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                    $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                    ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"),
                  "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                value: text,
                option: this
              };
          }) );
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          ui.item.option.selected = true;
          self._trigger( "selected", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
          });
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
          if ( !ui.item ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
            valid = false;
            select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
              if ( this.value.match( matcher ) ) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
              }
            });
            if ( !valid ) {
              // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
              $( this ).val( "" );
              select.val( "" );
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

    input.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };

    $( "<button> </button>" )
    .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
    .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
    .insertAfter( input )
    .button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
      },
      text: false
    })
    .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
    .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" )
    .click(function() {
      // close if already visible
      if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
        input.autocomplete("close");
        return;
      }
      // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
      input.autocomplete("search", "");
      input.focus();
    });
  },
  search: function(value) {
    this.element.autocomplete("search", value);
    this.element.focus();
  },
  destroy: function() {
    this.input.remove();
    this.button.remove();
    this.element.show();
    $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
  }
});
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `search` method is trying to use `autocomplete` on the `select` element where `autocomplete` is not used instead of the dynamically added `input` element

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.combobox", {
        _create : function() {
            var self = this;
            var select = this.element.hide(), selected = select
                    .children(":selected"), value = selected.val() ? selected
                    .text() : "";
            var input = $("<input />").insertAfter(select).val(value)
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay : 0,
                        minLength : 0,
                        source : function(request, response) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete
                                            .escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                            response(select.children("option").map(function() {
                                var text = $(this).text();
                                if (this.value
                                        && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                    return {
                                        label : text
                                                .replace(
                                                        new RegExp(
                                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)("
                                                                        + $.ui.autocomplete
                                                                                .escapeRegex(request.term)
                                                                        + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)",
                                                                "gi"),
                                                        "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                        value : text,
                                        option : this
                                    };
                            }));
                        },
                        select : function(event, ui) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            self._trigger("selected", event, {
                                        item : ui.item.option
                                    });
                        },
                        change : function(event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp("^"
                                                + $.ui.autocomplete
                                                        .escapeRegex($(this)
                                                                .val()) + "$",
                                        "i"), valid = false;
                                select.children("option").each(function() {
                                            if (this.value.match(matcher)) {
                                                this.selected = valid = true;
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        });
                                if (!valid) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match
                                    // anything
                                    $(this).val("");
                                    select.val("");
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

            this.input = input;
            input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
            };

            $("<button> </button>").attr("tabIndex", -1).attr("title",
                    "Show All Items").insertAfter(input).button({
                        icons : {
                            primary : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text : false
                    }).removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon").click(
                            function() {
                                // close if already visible
                                if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                                    input.autocomplete("close");
                                    return;
                                }
                                // pass empty string as value to search for,
                                // displaying all results
                                input.autocomplete("search", "");
                                input.focus();
                            });
        },
        search : function(value) {
            this.input.autocomplete("search", value);
            this.input.focus();
        },
        destroy : function() {
            this.input.remove();
            this.button.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$("select").combobox();
$("select").combobox("search","");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D4SFv/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you explain the line this.input = input; what is the difference between this.input and input?

Comment: `this.input` is an instance variable where `input` is a local variable which is accessible only inside the `_create` function. We need to access the `input` element in the search function also, so we need to save the reference to the element in the widget instance, it is done by assigning the reference of `input` variable to instance variable `this.input`

Comment: so its working except because I call $('select').combobox twice when I call this.input search its making both inputs visible. The first one is in the top left of the screen. I would think that's what this.input would avoid.